# Debian (jessie) 環境での curl エラー: (60)

Tags: ssl, debian

anacondaをpyenv経由でインストールしようとしたら以下のエラーがでました。環境は Debian (jessie) です。

```
/tmp/python-build.20160326063823.3417 ~
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
  using the --cacert option.
 If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
  the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
  problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
  not match the domain name in the URL).
 If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
  the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

調べてみたところ、ルート証明書が古いため出るエラーだそうですね。
そこで https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem から、新しいルート証明書を引っぱり、以下に示したサイトの方法で解決を試みました。

> 1. 使ってる認証局(globalsignとかverisign)のルート証明書を手に入れる。拡張子は.crtに。
> 2. /usr/share/ca-certificates以下に、1のxxxx.crt を置く。
> 3. /etc/ca-certificates.confに、2のpathを書
> 4. update-ca-certificatesを実行して、更新
>      (http://kamatari.github.io/blog/2015/03/12/how-to-install-root-certificate-on-debian/ より引用)

しかし結果は変わらず・・・解決手段を教えていただきたいです。

Comment: とりあえず証明書の確認をさせないのはどうでしょう。試していませんが`echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc`としてから実行したらいけそうな気がします。

Comment: ※端末の出力はコードブロックで（http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/8000）引用箇所は行頭に`>`を付けて引用ブロックにすると見やすくなります。また、2〜14はご自身で付けられた行番号でしたら、数字も含めて出力されたように見えてしまうので、取り除いた方がよいかと思います。

Comment: ＠Kenji Noguchi さん
上記コマンドを打ちこみ、source コマンドで反映させてから実行しましたが、同じエラーが出力されてしまいますね・・・

@unarist♦ さん
ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: う〜ん、直で打つ curl  コマンドでhttpsは通るんですけど、pyenv install の時だけ通らないです。なんだこれ・・・

Answer (score 1):

`export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

で通るようになりました。とりあえずよかった。